# Once kubernetes cpu limit is set, does container get more than the set limit

Tags: kubernetes, cpu, kubectl

lets say I have set a request of 1cpu and limit of 4 cpu, once the container is up, is it possible that the container gets more than 4 cpu if the node has more cpu available

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible - the limit is "hard". Even if there is more CPU resource available, the container will not be allowed to use it.